# Sudden change in reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

I don't understand. Not long ago I was sitting on 2,444 reputation, then I answered a question and got a minus score, lost 2 rep, then I answered correct another question of mine and regained the 2 I lost, so I was sitting on 2,444.

Now, only about a couple of minutes ago, I suddenly got (mysteriously) 6 reutation somehow without actually earning it, it just sort of changed without anything to tell me what I did to earn it.

***Why did this happen***?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect its because you deleted a question with 3 downvotes on it:

[image: reputation changes today]

You can view your reputation changes here:

https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/43257/natural?tab=reputation